# Polygon hole (ring) does not work

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

Why the polygon hole does not work?

[JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/s1whs53w/)

**code snippet (from fiddle):**

```js
var map;

(function() {

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: -23.6569389,
      lng: -46.5297752
    },
    zoom: 15,
  });


  var paths = [
    [
      new google.maps.LatLng(-23.644288322408464, -46.52812957763672),
      new google.maps.LatLng(-23.65368372747241, -46.5476131439209),
      new google.maps.LatLng(-23.6694460501439, -46.54031753540039),
      new google.maps.LatLng(-23.669563965596268, -46.5146541595459),
      new google.maps.LatLng(-23.65372303737324, -46.50959014892578)
    ],
    [
      new google.maps.LatLng(-23.656828482209104, -46.53083324432373),
      new google.maps.LatLng(-23.658754607146985, -46.53306484222412),
      new google.maps.LatLng(-23.658911840583425, -46.528472900390625)
    ]
  ]

  var shape = new google.maps.Polygon({
    map: map,
    paths: paths
  });

})();
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: If your question can't be understood without following a link, then it does not belong here.

Comment: The stackoverflow gives error . Will not let me post the code snipet or link JsFiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If outer ring goes 'clockwise', inner should go 'counter clockwise'. Change inner one to:

```
    [               
        new google.maps.LatLng(-23.658911840583425, -46.528472900390625),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-23.658754607146985, -46.53306484222412),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-23.656828482209104, -46.53083324432373)
    ]
```

Working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/s1whs53w/1/